# Why does this if statement succeed?

Tags: python

The if statement below succeeds and the value of s is printed.  However if you remove the : and/or whitespace conditionals it then fails.  I am confused as to why it is succeeding in the first place.

```
    s="( )"
    if ("if" and ":" and " ") in s:
        print(s)
```

Comment: What do you think `("if" and ":" and " ")` evaluates to?

Comment: this link explains better what is happening: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-43-logical-operators-on-string-in-python/

Answer (score 10):

The stuff in the parentheses is an expression that evaluates to a single value:

```
>>> "if" and ":" and " "
' '
>>> _ in "( )"
True
>>> ' ' in "( )"
True
>>> ("if" and ":" and " ") == ' '
True
```

`and` is like the ordinary boolean `AND`, but on steroids:

```
>>> 0 and 0
0
>>> 0 and 1
0
>>> 1 and 0
0
>>> 1 and 1
1
>>> 0 and 'hello'
0
>>> 'hello' and 0
0
>>> 'hello' and 'hello'
'hello'  # WAIT. That's illegal!
```

So, `and` returns the *last* truthy **object** in a *chain* of truthy objects (or the first non-truthy object it encounters). Notice that it returns an *object*, not strictly a boolean, like a binary AND would.

Comment: Can you explain why `"if" and ":" and " "` evaluates to `' '`?

Comment: @Steve, please see my edit

Comment: OK.  Did not know that about the and behavior.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what happens if you just run:

```
"if" and ":" and " "
```

You'll get:

```
" "
```

This is because you are first evaluating everything in the parentheses, then checking if the result of that is in `s`

To evaluate what you're looking for, you'll need something like:

```
if "if" in s and ":" in s and " " in s:
    print(s)
```

Alternatively:

```
if all(["if" in s, ":" in s, " " in s]):
    print(s)
```

Comment: the if all statement makes a lot of sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
a and b returns b if a is True, else returns a
```

So when we do `"if" and ":" and " "` is equivalent to `("if" and ":") and " "`

- `"if" and ":"` is `":"`
- `":" and " "` is `" "`

So, `"if" and ":" and " "` is `" "`
. Given `s="( )"` and the result `" "` is inside `s="( )"` 
Thats why `print(s)` is printed

Note `" "` is true meanwhile `""` is false